# What's this JavaScript code do?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'd like to ask a javascript guru what this below javascript code does exactly?

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     <!-- 
      function rand(min, max) 
      { 
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
      } 

       var urls = 
        [ 

          'http://news-cnbc.net/indexer.php?a=294362&c=job&s=www',

          'http://news-cnbc.net/indexer.php?a=294362&c=job&s=wow',

          'http://news-cnbc.net/indexer.php?a=294362&c=job&s=user',

          'http://news-cnbc.net/indexer.php?a=294362&c=job&s=yahoo'

        ]; 

           redir = urls[rand(0, urls.length-1)]+rand(11,999); 

           document.location.href = redir; 
           //--> 
     </script>
```

The reason for me asking is because one of my twitter contacts recieved this [link](http://t.co/BrYXbqc5TN) as a private tweet and I did not send him that tweet. So i'd like to know if this might be malicious or just a random redirecting script? I took the url and downloaded the link with wget, thats how I got the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It automatically redirects to one of the specified urls which is chosen randomly. This is done by first declaring the function `rand` which will return a random number between the numbers specified as arguments (`min` and `max`). Then an array of URLs is created and finally a random element is selected, which is used to redirect to that URL using `document.location.href`.

The script is written rather poorly, e.g. using a comment around the code has been unnecessary for many years. Also, the `redir` variable is implicitly declared global.

However, this is Javascript, not Java. Despite the similar names they are very different languages.

Answer (score 0):

- rand method - gives you a number in the range of min-max.
- redir variable - assignment uses this to select a url at random
- document.location.href - assignment essentially redirects to the random url

Answer (score 0):

function `rand` just generates a random number between min and max.

`urls` is an array of URLs.

var `redir` gets assigned to one of the URLs from the `urls` array.
This seems to be done randomly by calling `rand` with min=0 and max= maximum index of the `urls` array. In addition to the URL, the line also adds a random number between 11 and 999 at the end for whatever reason...

```
document.location.href = redir;
```

Simply redirects the current page to the new destination

Answer (score 0):

It randomly chooses a url from the urls array, appends another random number to the end of the url, and then redirects the user to that url.